# How to explain this simplification here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, laplace-transform, z-transform

I can't understand this simplification the book says without explanation. Could someone help me?

It is the calculatation/development of the transfer function of  a digital system composed by a dac (digital-to-analog converter, using a zero-order hold), analog subsystem [G(s)] and an adc (analog-to-digital converter, using a sampler).

L^{-1} is the operator of inverse laplace transform, Z in the operator o Z transform and the '*' means the function in sampled (discrete time).

I just wrote the last two lines.

[image]

The book is 'Digital Control Engineering' from Sam Fadali.

Comment: What does the different notations here mean? What is the Question about? Which book do you refer to?

Comment: Is that the convolution symbol far right of the first line?

Comment: @OveAhlman. I will write more details in the question.